# Linearly Interpolating a function not on a grid, but on a convex set of points in R

Tags: r, interpolation, linear-interpolation, function-approximation

Suppose I have the set of points

```
x1 = c(0,3,6) 
x2 = c(0,3,6)
```

and I want to interpolate the function

```
y <- function(x){x[1]^2 + x[2]^2}
```

On set the set of points such that

`x1 + x2 <= 6.`  That is...

```
z = 
    x1  x2
    0   0 
    0   3
    3   0
    6   0
    0   6
```

In reality, I do not know the function, but I know it's evaluation on each point of `z`.

The interpolation will fill in the gaps for any point in this set. For example, using the linear interpolation, I could evaluate it on anything in the rectangle

```
x1 + x2<=6
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you mean by "interpolate" when you have an analytic expression that gives exact values.

Comment: @42 In reality I don't, I only have evaluations of the function at the triangular grid points above.